# How to read a environmental variable in VC++

Tags: c++, winapi, environment-variables

I am a self learner of VC++. I am trying to read the environment variable and if particular variable is there then it should enable a checkbox. Here is the code

```
if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GR_STRIP") == NULL)
{
GetDlgItem(PRINTER)->Enabled = false ;                  
}
else

GetDlgItem(PRINTER)->Enabled = true ;
```

But I am getting following error

```
error C2660: 'GetEnvironmentVariable' : function does not take 1 parameter
error C2039: 'Enabled' : is not a member of 'CWnd'
```

I even tried changing

```
if (Environment::GetEnvironmentVariable("GR_STRIP") == NULL)
if (System::Environment::GetEnvironmentVariable("GR_STRIP") == NULL)
```

But none works. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you *really* using C++/CLI? If so, that first line should be using `::` and not `.`, but the docs say it should be ok.

Comment: Using C++/CLI and MFC together is possible, but not something one does everyday. Also what error(s) do you get when "none works"?

Comment: Using NULL in a C++/CLI program is not valid, you must use `nullptr`.  The mix of C++/CLI and MFC code is very suspicious.

Comment: @crashmstr I am using C++

Comment: @user3420781 `Environment::GetEnvironmentVariable` and `System::Environment::GetEnvironmentVariable` are .Net calls for C++/CLI. You *can* do this (check to see if you compile with the /CLR flag), but otherwise you need to look for Windows API calls. In this case `GetEnvironmentVariable` which takes more than one parameter.

Comment: @crashmstr when I changed as `Environment::GetEnvironmentVariable(`I am getting `error C2653: 'Environment' : is not a class or namespace name`

Comment: Instead can I use this `std::string string_variable;
static const std::string MY_VAR = "PATH";
int main()
{
    char const* temp = getenv(MY_VAR.c_str());
    if(temp != NULL)
    {
        string_variable = std::string(temp);            
    }   
}`

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the code you have posted is *very* confusing. If you were using C++/CLI, that should work (if you change to use `::` instead of `.`). If not, I don't know where you found that, but anything in the .Net Framework is off-limits.

Instead, you could use the Windows API call [GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It is declared like this:

```
DWORD WINAPI GetEnvironmentVariable(
  _In_opt_   LPCTSTR lpName,
  _Out_opt_  LPTSTR lpBuffer,
  _In_       DWORD nSize
);
```

I have not tested this, but I think it should do what you want (example *does not read the value*, since you seem to only want to check the existance:

```
DWORD size = 0;
GetEnvironmentVariable("GR_STRIP", NULL, &size); //get the size of the value
if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND)
{
    EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(PRINTER), FALSE);
}
else
{
    EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(PRINTER), TRUE);
}
```

**The "simpler" option would be to use the C library function [getenv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehxacec%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

```
if (getenv("GR_STRIP") == NULL)
{
    EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(PRINTER), FALSE);
}
else
{
    EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(PRINTER), TRUE);
}
```

I think somehow you are getting some mix of .Net, MFC, and Windows API code all mixed up. I have updated my answer to use [EnableWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you were in a MFC class, then it would be different.

Comment: I am getting `error C2039: 'Enabled' : is not a member of 'CWnd'`

Comment: @user3420781 I've changed it to use EnableWindow. If that does not work, then you *really* need to show more code.